# Angularjs redirect to https

Tags: angularjs, https, angular-ui-router

How can i redirect http page to https ?

I have tried this code block in login.config, but it goes to http and navigate to https. I want to resolve https firstly.

```
    resolve: {
        data: function ($q, $state, $timeout, $location, $window) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

                if ($location.protocol() !== 'https') {
                    $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
                }
                deferred.resolve(true);


            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect to https using webserver.

For example, if you're using nginx edit your server section of nginx.conf

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
       add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"; 

       [....]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are tackling the problem on the wrong level. Your AngularJS project is hosted on some kind of server (NodeJS, Apache HTTP, NGINX, whatever). This server should take care of doing the redirect!

For Apache HTTP, you might want to take a look at: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

In case of NGINX, you would have something like that in your config:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```